# How do I make changes in HTML code of website on wordpress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Website source:http://www.salefee.com/blog/

The above website is made on wordpress.In this I have an html code which looks like: `<div class="image-title-bg loading" style="padding-top: 140px;">`(found out using inspect element option in chrome)

I want to change the `padding-top:` to `50px`,But I am not able to find it in admin panel. Basically I am trying to reduce the image size on my first page of blog. Please help me out with this problem. Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Can u specify the area of the code in that website by attaching screenshot

Comment: Appearance → Editor

Comment: Learn to child theme - if you're going to be working with Wordpress themes and need the flexibility to customize them accordingly, this will be essential. Alternatively, explore plugin options, like "WP Add Custom CSS" (https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-add-custom-css/) - this plugin also adds an additional meta box into every post or page for styles specific only to those posts/pages (freeing up unnecessary clutter in the primary custom stylesheet, or reducing the length of internal styles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably will enjoy this WordPress plugin : [Simple Custom CSS](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/)
;)

Comment: Simple Custom CSS adds code to whole page, will be better to use plugin like Custom CSS Injector.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to find the relevant file and make changes in it.
Tip: You can search that html tag line in php files.

Answer (score 0):

To change html in Wordpress in admin part you should get to source of home page which can be usually found in Appearance Editor tab. Over there you can find php and html which you can edit. Or if you have FTP access you can track file there.